# Start C++ program from a java program

Tags: java, c++, process

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        freopen( "input.txt", "r", stdin );     
        freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout );
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout << s;  
        return 0; 
}
```

How to execute above C++ program's a.exe file using a java program ?
I tried using following but output.txt file is not being generated.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(..filepath.. )
```

Comment: Please post any error message you might be getting.. If you didn't get any, check if the `output.txt` file was written to a different directory than the one you expected.

Comment: Referring to @nfechner's comment, I think the files are being created into the current working directory of the java program running the process, not in the directory where the exe-file resides (unless they happen to be the same).

Comment: @nfechner, I didn't get any error message. I am using netbeans and 'input.txt, main.java, and the above c++ program's exe file are in same directory. So  output.txt should be produced in that directory only.

Comment: @kiesel-x: But is that directory also the *current* directory? The current directory doesn't need to be the directory the executable is located in; indeed, usually it won't be.

Comment: I just figured out that the problem occurs only in netbeans. It works fine in command prompt.

Comment: @kiesel-x Check the NetBeans and project directories. The file will probably be there...

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {

                Process pp=run.exec("c:\\a");
                BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getErrorStream()));

                //  Do your Stuff

                int exitVal = pp.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```